# ASP .NET Forms and Submit

Tags: asp.net, webforms, form-submit

I am new to ASP .Net Web Forms. Tried creating a Web Page going through Youtube Tutorials and now I'm stuck on this step where I have created a form with inputs and select using Bootstrap. Here is what my Frontend looks like which is in Default.aspx ---->

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <center class="form-group-lg">
                <form method="post" action="btnShow_Click">
                    <label>Token Number</label>    
            <input type="text"  name="txtCommand" id="txtCommand" class="text-center form-control" value="" runat="server" />
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label>Room Number</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="CounterID" id="CounterID" runat="server">
                                <option value="0">Select Room Number</option>
                                <option value="1">Room Number 01</option>
                                <option value="2">Room Number 02</option>
                                <option value="3">Room Number 03</option>
                                <option value="4">Room Number 04</option>
                                <option value="5">Room Number 05</option>
                                <option value="6">Room Number 06</option>
                                <option value="7">Room Number 07</option>
                                <option value="8">Room Number 08</option>
                                <option value="9">Room Number 09</option>
                                <option value="10">Room Number 10</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label>Department</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="CounterName" name="CounterName" runat="server">
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label>Terminal</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TerminalID" id="TerminalID" runat="server" value="000" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>Waiting Patients: <span id="label2">100</span></p>
                               <!-- <input type="text" readonly name="" id="label2" class="form-control" runat="server" value=""/> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>Total Patients: <span id="label1">100</span></p>
                                <!-- <input type="text" readonly name="label1" id="label1" class="form-control" runat="server" value=""/> -->        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" type="submit" runat="server" Text="Next" Width="56px"/>
                    </div>
                </form>

        </center>
        
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

and my Default.aspx.cs looks like --->>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GIMS_HIMS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            string depart = "select DeptCode, DepartmentName from Que_Master_Department where Active = 1";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(depart, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            CounterName.DataSource = dt;
            CounterName.DataTextField = "DepartmentName";
            CounterName.DataValueField = "DepartmentName";
            CounterName.DataBind();
            sqlconn.Close();
            btnShow.Click += btnShow_Click;
        }

        //Recall Button Commands Start Here
        private void Recall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CalcPatientRemain();
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GIMS_HIMS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            string query = " DELETE FROM Que_Delegation WHERE Token = '" + txtCommand.Value + "'";
            SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            scom.ExecuteNonQuery();


            query = " INSERT INTO Que_Delegation (Token, TerminalID, CounterID, CounterName, Dispatch) VALUES ('" + txtCommand.Value + "','" + TerminalID + "','" + CounterID + "','" + CounterName + "','False')";
            SqlCommand scom1 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
            scom1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
        //Recall Button Commands Ended



        //Next Button Commands Starts

        protected void Next_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GetToken();
            CalcPatientRemain();
            MainScreenDisplay();
        }

        public void GetToken()
        {
            try
            {
                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GIMS_HIMS"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
                String userqry = "SELECT TOP(1) Token, ID FROM Que_Management2 Where Department = '" + CounterName + "' AND Flag = 'False' ORDER BY  ID ASC";
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(userqry, sqlconn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        txtCommand.Value = dr[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    txtCommand.Value = string.Empty;
                }
                dr.Close();

                string query = "Update Que_Management2  SET Flag = 'True' WHERE Token = '" + txtCommand.Value + "'";
                SqlCommand scom2 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (txtCommand.Value != "")
                {
                    query = " DELETE FROM Que_Delegation";
                    SqlCommand scom3 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                    scom3.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    query = " INSERT INTO Que_Delegation (Token, TerminalID, CounterID, CounterName, Dispatch) VALUES ('" + txtCommand.Value + "','" + TerminalID + "','" + CounterID + "','" + CounterName + "','False')";
                    SqlCommand scom4 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                    scom4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string abc = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        public void CalcPatientRemain()
        {
            try
            {

                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GIMS_HIMS"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                DateTime Date1 = DateTime.Today;
                DateTime Date2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
                SqlDataReader dr;
                SqlCommand cmd;

                cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetPatientRemain", sqlconn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date2;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CounterName;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        label2.Value = (dr[0].ToString());
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();


                cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetPatientTotal", sqlconn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date2;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CounterName;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        label1.Value = (dr[0].ToString());
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                sqlconn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string abc = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        public void MainScreenDisplay()
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GIMS_HIMS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            string Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            string query = "";
            if (txtCommand.Value == "" || txtCommand.Value == null)
            {
                txtCommand.Value = "----";
            }


            if (CounterID.Value == "1")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T1 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C1 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom5 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom5.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "2")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T2 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C2 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom6 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom6.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "3")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T3 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C3 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom7 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom7.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "4")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T4 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C4 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom8 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom8.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "5")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T5 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C5 = '" + CounterID + "' , CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom9 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom9.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "6")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T6 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C6 = '" + CounterID + "' , CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom10 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom10.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "7")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T7 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C7 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom11 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom11.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "8")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T8 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C8 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom12 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom12.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "9")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T9 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C9 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom13 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom13.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else if (CounterID.Value == "10")
            {
                query = "Update Que_MainScreenDelegate2  SET T10 = '" + txtCommand.Value + "',  C10 = '" + CounterID + "', CMain = '" + CounterID + "', TMain = '" + txtCommand.Value + "', Sound = 'YES'  WHERE Date = '" + Date + "'";
                SqlCommand scom14 = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                scom14.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        //Next Button Commands Ended

        protected void btnShow_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
               //Page.GetType(),
               //"MessageBox",
               //"<script language='javascript'>alert('Hello');</script>"
            //);
            GetToken();
            CalcPatientRemain();
            MainScreenDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is its doing nothing. No changes are visible and the database also shows no updates. The button works when I trigger **OnClick** event on it as show in the commented function where I was showing a message on button click but same when I try my functions its not working. Can someone please help what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Dump this tutorial immediately. It teaches you an outdated framework (WebForms is [not maintained anymore and won't run on .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/migrate-web-forms)), and worse, it has giant SQL injection vulnerabilities (despite using parameterized queries - sometimes). Seriously, tutorials like this should be pulled.

If you want to create a .NET web application in 2021, use ASP.NET Core MVC or Razor Pages.

As for your error, you don't bind the `Recall_Click` handler to any button.